# Search Algorithm to find the k lowest values in a list

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, search, selection

I have a list that contains *n* double values and I need to find the *k* lowest double values in that list

- *k* is much smaller than *n*
- the initial list with the *n* double values is randomly ordered
- the found *k* lowest double values are not required to be sorted

**What algorithm would you recommend?**

At the moment I use *Quicksort* to sort the whole list, and then I take the first *k* elements out of the sorted list. I expect there should be a much faster algorithm.

**Thank you for your help!!!**

Comment: The algorithm is very much similar to quick sort. You can modify it a bit to get unordered list of all k smallest values.

Comment: I dont understand isn't it faster to just iterate through the list storing the k largest numbers by making k comparisons each time. Why do you need to sort it first. Searching is faster than sorting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [**selection algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) to find the kth lowest element and then iterate and return it and all elements that are lower then it. More work has to be done if the list can contain duplicates (making sure you don't end up with more elements that you need).

This solution is `O(n)`.
Selection algorithm is implemented in C++ as [`nth_element()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/nth_element/)

Another alternative is to **use a max [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29)** of size `k`, and iterate the elements while maintaining the heap to hold all k smallest elements.

```
for each element x:
   if (heap.size() < k):
      heap.add(x)
   else if x < heap.max():
      heap.pop()
      heap.add(x)
```

When you are done - the heap contains k smallest elements.

This solution is `O(nlogk)`

Comment: The *O(n log k)* is a worst case.  In fact, the algorithm typically runs only a little slower than *O(n)*.  See my answer for more detail and a link to where the running times have been studied and summarized.

Answer (score 10):

You could model your solution to match the [nlargest() code in Python's standard library](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3fa1414ce505/Lib/heapq.py#l183).

- Heapify the first *k* values on a maxheap.
- Iterate over the remaining *n - k* values.
- Compare each to the element of the top of the heap.
- If the new value is lower, do a *heapreplace* operation (which replaces the topmost heap element with the new value and then sifts it downward).

The algorithm can be surprisingly efficient.  For example, when n=100,000 and k=100, the number of comparisons is typically around 106,000 for randomly arranged inputs.  This is only slightly more than 100,000 comparisons to find a single minimum value.  And, it does about twenty times fewer comparisons than a full quicksort on the whole dataset.

The relative strength of various algorithms is studied and summarized at: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577573-compare-algorithms-for-heapqsmallest

Comment: Very nice answer I was wondering why the OP was suggesting doing a sort first when all you need to do is iterate over the elements and make comparisons at each step.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [partial_sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partial_sort/) algorithm from C++ standard library.

Comment: I think `nth_element` provides a more efficient solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [std::nth_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element). This is O(N) complexity because it doesn't sort the elements, it just arranges them such that every element under a certain N is less than N.

Answer (score 0):

you can use selection sort, it takes O(n) to select first lowest value. Once we have set this lowest value on position 1 we can rescan the data set to find out second lowest value. and can do it until we have kth lowest value. in this way if k is enough smaller then n then we will have complexity kn which is equivalent to O(n)...